# Object.create source explanation?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the MSDN network, can anyone explain me the `source-code`?

```
Object.create = (function() {
    var Temp = function() {};
    return function (prototype) {
      if (arguments.length > 1) {
        throw Error('Second argument not supported');
      }
      if (typeof prototype != 'object') {
        throw TypeError('Argument must be an object');
      }
      Temp.prototype = prototype;
      var result = new Temp();
      Temp.prototype = null;
      return result;
    };
  })();

function Guru(name){
   this.name = name;
}


function Shankar(name){
   this.name = name;
}

Guru.prototype = Object.create(Shankar.prototype);
```

What is confusing me here is `Temp.prototype = null;`, why are we setting it to `null` and `returning a instance of Temp` when we can return just `new Temp`

```
Temp.prototype = prototype;
return new Temp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just so that it doesn't cache the last object and keep it in memory if the original object gets deleted. Seems unnecessary in the vast majority of cases, but not a bad idea for prudence.